# Laravel - How to do referenctial integrity with where clause

Tags: laravel

In Laravel-8, I have this models:

Licence:

```
protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'number',
              'employee_id',
              'is_active',
          ];


public function employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Employee::class,'employee_id','id');
}
```

Employee:

```
protected $fillable = [
              'id',
              'first_name',
              'last_name',
              'other_name',
 ];

public function licences()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DriverLicence::class);
}
```

Employee can have more than one licence. But only one can be active.

I have this in the controller:

```
$employee = Employee::with('licences')->get();
```

How do I add where clause in the referential integrity that it should be licence where is_active is 1?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `whereHas()` to use condition in relation model.

```
$employee = Employee::with('licences')
->wherehas('licences',function($q){
  $q->where('is_active',1);
})
->get();
```

You can also do by adding relation and condition to get active licence

```
public function activeLicence()
{
    return $this->hasOne(DriverLicence::class,'employee_id')->where('is_activce',1);
}
```

You can access active licence as below:

```
$employee->activeLicence;
```

Comment: This can ba added in the model under a method, ex `getActiveLicense()`